# Как добавить кнопку в конец списка

Tags: android, listview, button

Здравствуйте.
Необходимо разместить кнопку под списком, что бы она находилась после последнего элемента списка. Список статический.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

читаем тут

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-a-footer-in-listview

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/114-urok-55-header-i-footer-v-spiskah-headerviewlistadapter

Comment: Благодарю!

Comment: две ссылки не достойны быть ответом. Максимум - комментарием.

Comment: "бесполезное дублирование" == "зло"

Comment: Борщь == еда    
При чем тут дублирование? Я пишу, что это нужно было оформить не как ответ, а как комментарий.